# Why is azure disk throughput half of whats advertised?

Tags: azure, azure-disk

We're running a standard B8ms VM with a 257GB Premium SSD. According to the docs it says the throughput should be `Up to 170 MB/second Provisioned 100 MB/second`

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/managed-disks/

However when i test it, the throughput looks to be about 35 MB/Second

```
▶  dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/test1.img bs=1G count=1 oflag=dsync
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 30.8976 s, 34.8 MB/s
```

Is there something else i need to account for in order to maximize the throughput?

Answer (score 0):

You have diffrent limits, you have the IOPS limit on the disk and you have the Throughput limit on the disk. If you use bigger blocks when testing you will hit the througput limit and if you use smaller blocks you will hit the IOPS limit.

Then you have the VM limits and you have the Disk/Storage limits. So there is many things to take into consideration when doing this  types of tests.

And you also have the caching settings to take into consideration on the disks.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/disks-benchmarks